# Creating custom error page in Lumen

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, lumen

How do I create custom view for errors on Lumen? I tried to create `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`, like what we can do in Laravel 5, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The answer by lukasgeiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30233308/792066) is *almost* correct, but the response made with the `view` function will always carry the `200` HTTP status code, which is problematic for crawlers or any user agent that relies on it.

The [Lumen documentation](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/errors#render-method) tries to address this, but the code given does not work because it is copied from Laravel's, and Lumen's stripped down version of the `ResponseFactory` class is missing the `view` method.

This is the code which I'm currently using.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

[...] 

public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
        $status = $e->getStatusCode();

        if (view()->exists("errors.$status")) {
            return response(view("errors.$status"), $status);
        }
    }

    if (env('APP_DEBUG')) {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    } else {
        return response(view("errors.500"), 500);
    }
}
```

This assumes you have your errors stored in the `errors` directory under your views.

Answer (score 16):

Errors are handled within `App\Exceptions\Handler`. To display a 404 page change the `render()` method to this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
        return response(view('errors.404'), 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

And add this in the top of the Handler.php file:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

**Edit:** As @YiJiang points out, the response should not only return the 404 view but also contain the correct status code. Therefore `view()` should be wrapped in a `response()` call passing in `404` as status code. Like in the edited code above.

Comment: `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;` might need to added, since it's on a different namespace. (Comment from [Carlo V](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1025467/carlo-v))

Comment: This is problematic because your response won't carry the correct HTTP status code. Lumen's documentation addresses this, but it is also wrong, because it is copied over from Laravel's (the `ResponseFactory` class doesn't have the `view` method it does in Laravel). I ended up with `return response(view("errors.$status")->render(), $status);`

Comment: Thanks @YiJiang, you're awesome!

Comment: Thank you @YiJiang for pointing out to add a status to the response as well. I tried to edit the answer above but it was rejected. In my opinion an error page should definitely return a 404 HTTP response code. The code in the answer above returns a 200 response code, which is wrong and leads to bots being confused.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me, but I got it working with:

```
if($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
  return view('errors.404');
}
```

You might also want to add

```
http_response_code(404)
```

to tell the search engines about the status of the page.