# Custom 404 page in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I'm new to Lumen and want to create an app with this framework. Now I have the problem that if some user enters a wrong url => http://www.example.com/abuot (wrong) => http://www.example.com/about (right),  I want to present a custom error page and it would be ideal happen within the middleware level.

Furthermore, I am able to check if the current url is valid or not, but I am not sure how can I "make" the view within the middleware, the response()->view() won't work.

Would be awesome if somebody can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating custom error page in Lumen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233211/creating-custom-error-page-in-lumen)

Comment: @maiorano84 that documentation is for Laravel and won't work the same for Lumen. The exception needs to be caught and handled manually.

Comment: It is definitely a duplicate, but unfortunately the answer here is better

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Seeing as errors are handled in `App\Exceptions\Handler`, this is the best place to deal with them.

If you are only after a custom 404 error page, then you could do this quite easily:

Add this line up the top of the `Handler` file:

`use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;`

Alter the `render` function to look like so:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
        return response(view("errors.404"), 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

This assumes your custom 404 page is stored in an errors folder within your views, and will return the custom error page along with a 404 status code.

Comment: thanks, i used it both on production and development environment

Comment: The ```instanceof``` conditional did not work for me. Replaced with ```$e->getStatusCode() == 404``` and it worked.

Comment: for those who the if does not work make sure you import the class `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;` or specify the full path in the if statement `($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException)`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add this so that when for example blade blows up the error page hander will not throw a PHP error.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
 {
   if (method_exists('Exception','getStatusCode')){

     if($exception->getStatusCode() == 404){
       return response(view("errors.404"), 404);
     }

     if($exception->getStatusCode() == 500){
       return response(view("errors.500"), 404);
     }
   }
   return parent::render($request, $exception);
 }
```

Comment: Not worked for me dear, still getting old 404 screen in Lumne 8 version. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Lumen 8.x version` and below solution worked for me:

**File path: ‎⁨▸ ⁨app⁩ ▸ ⁨Exceptions⁩ ▸ ⁨Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    // start custom code
    if($exception->getStatusCode() == 404){
        return response(view("errors.404"), 404);
    }
    if($exception->getStatusCode() == 500){
        return response(view("errors.500"), 404);
    }
    // end custom code

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Do not forget to create `errors` folder at `/resources/views/errors` and create the below 2 new files in `errors` folder:

`404.blade.php`

`500.blade.php`

and add html tags and messages in those files what you want to add.

Happy to help you. Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: This looks promising to me but I get in Lumen 8 due to getStatusCode() not being found.   Where is this located ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation. `response(view("errors.404"), 404)`did not work for me, so I changed it as follows:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
        return response(view('errors.404')->render(), 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```